# Python ggplot (ggpy) without Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, python-ggplot

all the examples that I've found on https://github.com/yhat/ggpy show code in jupyter notebook. Is this a requirement or can I also visualise a chart while using Pycharm or running a script from terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `p` is a ggpy object, then simply `print(p)` will show the plot in Pycharm or command line.

(self-answer migrated from [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105469/python-ggplot-ggpy-without-jupyter-notebook#comment85216294_49105649))

Answer (score 0):

jupyter is the notebook which is an alternative to IDE e.g. Pycharm.

when you use Pycharm and want to use ggplot matplotlib style then you just do as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

EDIT:

`plt.show()` should do the job for you

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure this answer my question. I don't want to use matplotlib, and I know what Pycharm is. I have actually realised how to achieve what I wanted: if p is my ggpy object, simply print(p) will let me see the plot in pycharm or command line.

Comment: Jupyter notebooks can be edited and run within Pycharm... I don't see how that makes the one an alternative to the other?

Comment: @giac_man: I posted your comment as an answer, because that's apparently what it is.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett thanks - In regards to why one is an alternative to the other: Jupyter notebooks are horrible in github, because you can't see changes line by line.

Comment: *Non sequitur*.